# How to use jQuery commands on the parent document inside a iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

**Info:** I've read a lot of questions about [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) accessing  [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe) and such so, but i've not found anything about the inverse that is: Inside the [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe) access the parent document to change, and bind some elements from the parent document.

**Problem:** I dont know how to do that.

**What i've tried:**

**1st try:**

```js
function ajax(){
  $(document.parentNode).contents().find("#ajaxLoading").show();
  document.parentNode.contentWindow.$('#mainFrame').load(function(){
    $(document.parentNode).contents().find('#ajaxLoading').hide();
    $(document.parentNode).contents().find('#pnlContentHeader').removeClass('front');
  });
}
```

**2nd try:**

```js
function ajax(){
  document.parentNode.$("#ajaxLoading").show();
  document.parentNode.$('#mainFrame').load(function(){
    document.parentNode.$('#ajaxLoading').hide();
    document.parentNode.$('#pnlContentHeader').removeClass('front');
  });
}
```

**3rd try:**

```js
function ajax(){
  document.parentNode.find("#ajaxLoading").show();
  document.parentNode.find('#mainFrame').load(function(){
    document.parentNode.find('#ajaxLoading').hide();
    document.parentNode.find('#pnlContentHeader').removeClass('front');
  });
}
```

I need some help with that, i dont really know what i'm doing...

Comment: you want `window.parent` or `window.top`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work using `window.parent.document`:

```
$(window.parent.document).find("#ajaxLoading").show();
```